# Facing issue in AWS dynamo db trigger

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I created a dynamodb table and associated a lambda function to same to be triggered. Initially it works fine and for every insertion I noticed the lambda execution in *cloudwatch* but after few more testing like frequently adding and deleting records from table it automatically stops triggering lambda. I am unable to find out actual reason behind it.

Please help me out here...

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch Logs and Metrics would be useful in determining the exact cause of your problem.

In the meantime, I would suggest configuring the DynamoDB event source with a `On-failure destination` - an SQS queue or SNS topic for records that can't be processed. When Lambda discards a batch of records because it's too old or has exhausted all retries, it sends details about the batch to the queue or topic. This configuration is part of the [DestinationConfig data type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_DestinationConfig.html).

You should also check the state of your Lambda function. A variety of things, like VPC attachment, can impact the function's state. You can check the state via the cli:

`$ aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name my-function`

```
{
    "FunctionName": "my-function",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
    "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
    "VpcConfig": {
        "SubnetIds": [
            "subnet-071f712345678e7c8",
            "subnet-07fd123456788a036",
            "subnet-0804f77612345cacf"
        ],
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            "sg-085912345678492fb"
        ],
        "VpcId": "vpc-08e1234569e011e83"
    },
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "InProgress",
    ...
}
```

If your state is Inactive or Pending, check the `LastUpdateStatusReasonCode` - this would tell you if there is a permission error, a lack of VPC IP addresses for the function, etc.

Other common errors would be a change in the [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). Ensure someone didn't alter it and remove `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` and `AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole` permissions. In particular, for DynamoDB Streams processing, you need the following:

- dynamodb:DescribeStream
- dynamodb:GetRecords
- dynamodb:GetShardIterator
- dynamodb:ListStreams

Note that if you add an on-failure destination, which I strongly suggest for debugging and error handling, you will also need a permission for it, depending on the destination service you select:

- Amazon SQS – sqs:SendMessage
- Amazon SNS – sns:Publish

The event source mapping that reads records from your DynamoDB stream invokes your function synchronously and retries on errors. If the function is throttled or the Lambda service returns an error without invoking the function, Lambda retries until the records expire or exceed the maximum age that you configure on the event source mapping.

If the function receives the records but returns an error, Lambda retries until the records in the batch expire, exceed the maximum age, or reach the configured retry limit. **With the default settings, this means that a bad record can block processing on the affected shard for up to one day.**

I would suggest configuring your function's event source mapping with use-case appropriate retries and max record age. Also, enable `Split batch on error`, which splits batches of records from the stream into two before retrying, potentially **isolates bad records** and **works around timeout issues**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your Lambda code cannot handle exceptions. When you delete an item from DynamoDB that action is also sent downstream to Lambda - probably Lambda does not know how to handle it. But it will keep trying. If you keep adding items then you're fine, but when you delete items you'll get an exception.